# The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version in vs code terminal

Tags: powershell

I get an error when I try

```
 mkdir python && cd python && echo python > index.py
```

in my VS code terminal. [This](https://youtu.be/eS88Twv3cUE?t=95) is the tutorial I am following.
[image: here]

Comment: I don't think we have chaining operators in PowerShell, you would need to use `;` instead (_which I'm not sure can be considered the same since chain is based of last exit code ?_)

Comment: I tried that, did not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

could you please check your PowerShell version using the following command

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

As far I know, one of the new features of Powershell 7.0 is Pipeline chain operators: `&&` and `||`
so this should work only on powershell 7

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this was implemented in PS Core!

Comment: yes, I also thought that such a feature should be exist on powershell (it already exist on linux from decades ) and amazed that Microsoft made it on v.7 .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think we have such a thing as `&&` chain operators in Windows PowerShell, would be nice though. This is pretty close to what you're looking for, it is a lot more verbose as you can see.

Note, *`mkdir`* is an alias for [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-5.1).

```
$folder = New-Item python -ItemType Directory
if($?){ Push-Location $folder; 'python' > index.py; Pop-Location }
```

Based on [Mahmoud Moawad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569060/15339544) answer, if you're running PowerShell Core:

```
New-Item python -ItemType Directory -Force 1>$null && Push-Location python && 'python' > index.py && Pop-Location
```